# Did Summer 19 break NamedCredentials using Auth. Provider in Sandboxes

Tags: namedcredentials, auth-provider, summer19

This weekend some of our sandboxes was upgraded to summer 19. before that we were able to query consumer secret from the Auth. Provider used in the named credentials. 
After the summer release we are not able to do this anymore. 
Can any of you replicate this

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Endpoint, AuthProviderId, AuthProvider.AuthorizeUrl, AuthProvider.ConsumerKey, AuthProvider.ConsumerSecret FROM NamedCredential
```

In production this gives the consumer secret it also works in sandboxes that are on on summer 19.

Can any of you confirm this?

Comment: I now have a case with salesforce support tier 3. Has anyone been able to reproduce?

Comment: It seems be related to a security fix in Summer 19. Will hear back today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issus was related to a security fix. They have now issued a bugfix. 
They said that they recommend using Merge Fields with named credentials. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm 
For now the issue is fixed and it will not impact production when Summer '19 goes live.